# Missing Types in Gatsby with GatsbyImageData and Mdx

Tags: typescript, gatsby, gatsby-image, mdxjs

I have a site using Gatsby (with `gatsby-plugin-image`) and I am trying to refactor to Typescript. This is my first experience with ts

I have a layout page that uses a pagequery that pulls Mdx data, however I am missing some types though and wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I am struggling to find what type I should import and use for:

```
childImageSharp: {fixed:???}
MdxQuery = {body: ???}`
```

On the old `gatsby-image` means of handling images it used the type of `FixedObject` but this no longer works.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please for these missing types?

```
type Frontmatter = {
  title: string;
  titlestrap: string | null;
  category: string;
  slug: string;
  metaDescription: string | null;
  author?: string | null;
  featuredImage: {
    childImageSharp: {
      fixed: any; // what here?
      gatsbyImageData: IGatsbyImageData;
    };
  };
};

type MdxQuery = {
  id: string;
  body: any; // what here?
  frontmatter: Frontmatter;
  excerpt: string;
};
```